# Optimal Path Between Two Points in Force Field

Tags: mathematical-physics, variational-analysis

The brachistochrone problem says: If we were to have two objects separated by a horizontal distance $X$ and vertical distance $Y$ under free fall acceleration $g$, and then put a bead through a wire, we would find that the path that warrants the shortest time between both points is not a line, but rather the tautochrone curve.

I want to generalise this problem to add more practicality:

If we were to have two points $A (0, 0)$ and $B (x, y)$ in a Cartesian plane and an object starts at point $A$ with a velocity vector $\vec v$, what path would give the shortest time of travel between both points if the plane is in a force field $\vec F (x,y)$ that induces acceleration (assuming bounds of acceleration are finite and continuous, i.e. $-a \leq 0 \leq a$).

Comment: But, to clarify, you are given the force field (which induces the acceleration) on the plane to start with. It is just not a constant force field. Saying "at any time" muddles the issue and I don't know what it means. If the force field is non-conservative, you won't have a potential energy and the usual approach will fail.

Comment: That makes sense. I can edit that in my question.

Comment: How exactly generalized? In a Newtonian planetary gravitational field, inverse squared Law operates. Constant gravity/ acceleration for a cycloid. You have to specify the Law of acceleration in the question..

Comment: Well, at least in the brachistochrone problem, the fact that acceleration is constant and only in one direction leaves me feeling as if it can be generalised. If acceleration can be variable and can change direction, then I’m not convinced that the same cycloidal path gives minimum time.

Comment: There would be some practicalities in this also, like for example, skiing where you have to go between two poles as fast as possible.

Comment: I suspect the best you can do is have a variational expression representing the minimal path without knowing behavior of $F$. Have you gone through the variational argument for the brachistochrone problem?

Comment: I suggest you start by assuming $\vec F = \nabla\phi$ and see if you can solve the conservative case.

Comment: Ok thanks, I’ll give it a try and come back here with any results I find.